# Uh-oh! Unable to provision site on Linux Mint 21.1 OS

Tags: wordpress

I cannot create new sites nor import .zip files of other site onto local by flywheel.

Any time I try to create a site or import one, I get the following error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytDNp.png)

This software worked on my work pc, which was using Windows 11 but I am currently using my personal laptop, which is using Linux Mint 21.1 OS.

The current Local version is 7.0.0+6386.

I tried to uninstall and install again. I tried changing the router modes to see if anything changes. Nothing has changed. I have tried rolling back to prior versions of Local by flywheel but nothing works at this stage.

I was expecting for the Local to allow me to create a new site or import sites, because other people have tried these steps and it works for them.